# Unknown Icon on iPad Lock Screen

Tags: ipad, bug

[image]

I don’t know what that white glob like thing right over left upper corner, I think it’s kinda bug , it just doesn’t look good can any body tell me what is that and how can I take it out

Comment: Please specify the version of iOS running on your iPad along with make and model.

Comment: @NimeshNeema iOS 12.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you have no SIM card in your iPad. It seems to appear in place of the cellular icon. It looks to possibly be a bug. You could [try restoring](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/9wnkvi/what_is_this_big_white_dot_in_top_right_corner_it/) it, that could fix the issue.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8566966